# Load array and display based on state of uiswitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

Im trying to develop an app that displays a random truth or dare type question, however the user has the ability to turn off truths or dares in option. I have successfully managed to get the app to display a random quote from a plist file from either the truth or dare array also i have managed to program two switch buttons in the user options view controller.

My problem is how would i go about displaying only a truth or dare or both if the user has turned on of the uiswitchs off?

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender 
{
    if (!self.plistArray) 
    {
       NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"data" ofType:@"plist"];


       NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray *plistArray1 = plistDict[@"truth"];
        }

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];
        }

        self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);
    //check to see if array is empty and display message
    if ([plistArray count] == 0) 
    {
        self.text.text = @"array empty";
    }

    else
    {
        //display random quote from array
        int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;

        self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
        [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
    }
}
```

That is my attempt however it will not run and i have the feeling it wont ddo the job i need.

Basicly i need it to display only truth if the user has selected that to true or only dare if that is selected or both if both are set to true.

EDIT
sorry the problem with the above code is the plist isnt being loaded and it is scipping straight to  if array ==0 {

How do i ensure it loads the array and then checks which arrays to load from the plist file?

Any help is greatly appreciated

This is the code before i tried to add if statements. Im so confussed how best to do this

```
    - (IBAction)shownext:(id)sender {


    //load array and check then cycle through this untill array is empty. Array will add two arrays from plist file.



    if (!self.plistArray) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                          @"data" ofType:@"plist"];



        NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict[@"truth"];



        NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

        self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);
   //check to see if array is empty and display message
    if ([plistArray count] == 0) {
        self.text.text = @"array empty";
    }
else    {
//display random quote from array
    int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;


    self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
    [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];

    }
}
```

Comment: You talked about UISwitch's in your question, but I do not see any UISwitch code, only UIButton.

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: i cant seem to get all the code to talk to each other. I cant think of the logic on how to determin which way to check the status and then display the results

Comment: I have the uiswitch talking to the second view controller so didnt see need to post this code. All im trying to do is display only truth or dare or both based on the input the user gives. The code for checking the state of the ui switch is working above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have a switch for truth and one for dare I hope you have something in place to deal with when the user turns both switches off and doesn't understand why they get nothing (trust me it will happen).

For the rest I'm not sure exactly how you app works but I will take a guess. I'm thinking you have a utility style app with the main UI in one view and then an info button that flips to a second view where the switches are. I'm also guessing that there is a button in the main view that retrieves a truth or dare string. My final assumption, based on your code above, is that when the user changes the state of a switch that writes a user default that you've use a `#define` to keep out spelling mistakes.

When your view loads you should load both arrays in case the user changes their mind in the middle of using your app and turns on both options or changes from one to the other. Depending on how many entries you have in each of those arrays you might consider creating a combined array as well to simplify things.

When the button is pressed you should then look at the defaults and see if you need to look at both arrays or just one (the below is pseudo code)

```
if(truth && dare) {
  // if you have a combined array pick a random element from it.
  // otherwise first randomly pick one of the arrays to pick from.
}
else if (truth) {
  // get a random element from the truth array
}
else {
  // get a random element from the dare array
}
```

Also, your current checks of the switch values will *always* return no unless you are doing extra work in the switch view controller. You should be using `[defaults setBool:<UISwitch.isOn> forKey:<#definedKeyHere>]` and `[defaults boolForKey:<#definedKeyHere>]`.

Comment: Thanks the problem is i have combined both arrays into plistarray in the code so how would i pick a random array?

Comment: Basicly you are correct i want the user to be able to either select one or other. If i post full code later will you be able to review this please?

Comment: Looking at the code you have above it seems you plist file has a dictionary with two arrays in it. Provided that this is the case you can just keep those two arrays around and create a third one that is both combined. Text doesn't take much memory so unless you have several million entires the three arrays won't be a problem. If you need to use one array change the elements from strings to dictionaries that have a key for the text and one for the type. Then when picking a random entry you look at its type, if it is wrong try the next one in line.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to know what part isn't working.  For one thing, it might help to store your flags as NSNumber objects instead of strings (could your string comparison be failing?).  Then you could do something like:

```
if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue])
```

Use a literal to add the actual NSNumber - @YES or @NO.

Consider changing your logic to something like:

```
VERIFY CODE - doing this freehand:

if (!self.plistArray) 
{
   self.plistArray = [NSMutableArray array];
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"data" ofType:@"plist"];

   // why are you loading this twice?
   NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue])
    {
        [self.plistArray addObject:plistDict[@"truth"]];
    }

    if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"dareonoff"] boolValue])
    {
        [self.plistArray addObject:plistDict[@"dare"]];
    }
}
```

I am assuming that your code to load the Plists is working.  Verify all your keys match what's in the Plist. Set a breakpoint and verify.

Calling a method on a nil object is a no-op in Objective C.  So, it'll happily ignore calls to nil objects without telling you.  Verify you have what you think you have.

Also, here:

```
    //display random quote from array
    int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;

    self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
    [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
```

Consider using arc4random_uniform(self.plistArray.count) as it avoids modulo bias in the generator.
Now, this just gives you say 0 or 1 if you have two elements.  Are you sure the two dictionary keys, "truth" and "dare" actually point to arrays?

Ok, everything working to this point.  Now, you have an array of ARRAYS!  So you need to randomly pick a question array, and THEN randomly pick a question.

Something like:

```
    //get random array
    int randArrayIndex = arc4random_uniform(self.plistArray.count);
    NSArray* questionArray = self.plistArray[randArrayIndex];

    //get random question 
    int randQuestionIndex = arc4random_uniform([questionArray count]);
    NSString* randomQuestion = questionArray[randQuestionIndex];

    self.text.text = randomQuestion;

    // remove question
    [questionArray removeObjectAtIndex:randQuestionIndex];
```

Something like that anyway.  Of course, assuming you are storing NSStrings in those Plist arrays.